# Why reference collapsing rules work only for templates?

Tags: c++11, templates, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void f1(T&& r1){
    std::cout<<r1;
}

void f2(int&& r2){
    std::cout<<r2;
}

int main() {
    int&& x = 42;
    f1(x); //line 1: No error here. Why?
    f2(x);//line2: Error here. why?
}
```

I think that I understand why we have an error on line 2. The variable x is **rvalue reference** to int 42 and being considered as an expression, x is a **lvalue**. In function f2, the input r2 is a **rvalue reference** and thus can only bind to a **rvalue**, so we have an error.

Now, my question is, why the seemingly equivalent code in function f1 works just fine? I know this might have something to do with the reference collapsing rules, i.e., when we execute f1(x), we are trying to instantiate f1 with type parameter T being int &&, so the input parameter T&& is int&& &&, which then reduces to int &&. In other words, we have:

```
void f1<int &&>(int &&);
```

which means this instantiation is exactly the same as in function f2, right? So why f1 works and f2 does not?

Comment: `T` is not `int &&`. `T` is `int &`. Which collapses to `int &`. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76666156bcf580f4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why does line 1 works?

There is a special rule in template argument deduction that was introduced to permit **perfect-forwarding**. In the context of template argument deduction, `T&&` is not an *rvalue reference* but a *forwarding reference* instead.

If an *lvalue* is passed to a function template taking a *forwarding reference*, the type parameter is deduced as `T&` instead of `T`. This allows *reference collapsing* to take place: `T& &&` becomes `T&`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

> If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of std::forward Note: in class template argument deduction, template parameter of a class template is never a forwarding reference (since C++17))
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> int f(T&&);       // P is an rvalue reference to cv-unqualified T (forwarding reference)
> template<class T>
> int g(const T&&); // P is an rvalue reference to cv-qualified T (not special)
>
> int main()
> {
>     int i;
>     int n1 = f(i); // argument is lvalue: calls f<int&>(int&) (special case)
>     int n2 = f(0); // argument is not lvalue: calls f<int>(int&&)
>
> //  int n3 = g(i); // error: deduces to g<int>(const int&&), which
>                    // cannot bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue
> }
> ```

---

In line 2 there is no template argument deduction going on - `f2` takes an *rvalue reference*, and will reject anything that will not bind to that. *Lvalues* do not bind to *rvalue references*.

Comment: Let me just do a quick recap of what I did wrong. When we try to deduce the template type parameter T, we should consider the input as an expression, even if it might also be a variable. As a variable, x has type **int&&** (i.e., a rvalue reference), but as an expression, x has type int and is a lvalue. Now, according to the _special rule_ you just mentioned,  when we call f1(x), the compiler deduces the type of T as **int&**, not **int** (nor **int&&**). Finally, based on the reference collapse rules, we have **int& &&**  reduced to **int&**. Am I right this time?

Comment: @ivy: sounds correct to me. Here's an empirical proof for the `int&` deduction: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vIEe4WtqkVtMRtlF